# Can't update the PHP 5.3 to higher version on CentOS 6.1

Tags: php, centos-6

I have a server running on CentOS 6.1 ..
And currently having PHP 5.3.29

I tried installing a newer version but the issue is the i can't remove the older version ..
I am confused how to begin well !

Even i tried to change the CentOS 6 to 7 .. but still didn't get the correct way ..

i used this command :

```
yum remove php-common
```

and getting this :

```
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * cpanel-addons-production-feed: 185.53.12.144
 * epel: mirror.de.leaseweb.net
 * remi-php70: mirror.dogado.de
 * remi-safe: mirror.dogado.de
 * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
No Packages marked for removal
```

Any one can help ?!

Answer (score 0):

> I have a server running on CentOS 6.1

CentOS 6 have reached its end of life, you really have to use a maintained version, CentOS 7 or 8

> - webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com

webtatic is a dead project, no update for [> 1 year](https://github.com/webtatic-rpms)

For a proper installation simply follow the [Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/).

> yum remove php-common
> No Packages marked for removal

Which means your are not using this set of package.

Check where is installed PHP

```
 $ which php
```

Check which package is installed

```
$ rpm -qf $(which php)
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply ..
I tried to use the wizard , but it didn't work with me ..

and i got those result for about the PHP 
`root@server [~]# which php
/usr/local/bin/php
root@server [~]# rpm -qf $(which php)
file /usr/local/bin/php is not owned by any package
`

Comment: So you have a manually installed (from sources) php. You have to remove it to be able to install a packaged version.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64940391/php-5-3-to-7-3-upgrade-failed